# How to Add Windows 7 visual style in winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7

I have to change the look and feel of my win form application of .net framework 3.5.
So i want to add window 7 theme or visual style, Is any sample application available?
and also suggest what to do change look and feel of my application?

Comment: Also take a look at this Hanselman blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode45KickingButtOnWindows7AndWindowsXP.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The *Windows API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework* contains source code for using Win7/Vista features from .Net.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score -1):

write your own MANIFEST file for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="9.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="ApplicationName.exe"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>YourApplicationName</description>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Save it as .exe.manifest OR embed it within the .resx file.